# Where is my SQLite database location on RPi2 SD card (Windows IOT OS)?

Tags: sd-card, pi-2, windows-iot, sqlite

My SQLite project is working on Raspberry Pi 2 (with all function insert, delete, update ..) but where are my SQLite database files located?

I followed this way I found my SQLite database location on when I compiled on x86 - localmachine:

My SQLite project VS 2015

```
Package.appxmaifest\Packaging\Package name : 9fd5092f-7eb0-4607-bc31-e41f02c4f1e4
```

and

```
C:\Users\computerName\AppData\Local\Packages\PackageName\LocalState
```

That path contains my SQLite DB files.

But when I compile ARM - RemoteMachine I can't find my SQLite database file on Windows IOT OS device RPi2 (in the SD card).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to specify the path of the actual file (using `package SQLite.Net-PCL` - You didn't say what package you are using)

```
path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");

conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
```

Print out the path somewhere and you should be able to find it. Its possible the default path is buried somewhere deep.